# Is resetting the tab bar controller allowed?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to use this code:

```
((AppDelegate)UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate).MainTabBarController.Reset();
```

but I want to know if it is actually legal to reset the tab bar controller in my app?

Comment: In what circumstance you want to reset your `UITabBarController` ?

Comment: I don't understand this question. You need to edit your question and be more detailed and explain what you want to do. As far as I can tell so far you have a `UITabBarController`, and you want to "reset" it? Define "reset" in this context.

Comment: reset in the context i want to release all the view controllers and assign it again but that TABBAR CONTROLLER is designed from the xib .  i am  giving an option for the user to select the language from the app but when the user select the language option i am unable to update the views with selected language because the tabbarcontroller is already loaded from the MAINWINDOW.xib ,so now i want to reset the tabbar controller to show the UI in the user selected language'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple discourages to give the users the option to select languages. Instead you should localize your text-resources, and use NSLocalizedString.